# How do I safely run 70 VDC wiring in a drop ceiling?

Tags: electrical

I am running a 70 V sound system in my drop ceiling and I had 3 questions.

My area follows the 2017 NEC.

1. Does 70 VDC (roughly 1.5 A) in CMP 14-2 speaker wire need to be in conduit in a drop ceiling?
2. Can I use the low voltage remodeling boxes to output the terminal in the wall?  Or should I used a standard wiring box?
3. Will standard speaker port wall plates (the kind where you use banana plugs to connect speaker) work with 70v?

Comment: "low voltage" typically refers to 50V or less. And there are reasons for that. Your 70V system may really push you into dangerous territory - it is more than half-way to a standard 120V. NEC is relatively silent on low voltage wiring (other than "keep it separate from higher voltage wiring") but once you cross that line, you need to follow a *lot* of rules.

Comment: Also, DC is much more dangerous than AC at the same voltage.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What kind of connectors do the 70V speakers have?

Comment: Traditionally a 70 volt audio system normally employs transformers to connect speakers to the audio bus. This means the 70 volt system is AC, not DC. Are you sure your system is DC? Do you have a specific amplifier picked out? Its installation instructions may provide guidance as to whether the 70 volt circuit is power-limited or has any other special characteristic that would spare you from having to use mains-style wiring materials and methods.

Comment: Audio systems have there own section in code the amplifiers are usually limited or classified as class 2 or class 3 the actual output defines which classification it is but they are both power limited as identified by code see article 640. @greg hill yes audio signals are audio not really AC and not DC remember AC is a sinusoidal wave form audio looks like noise but can be identified as having a frequency range of 20-20khz so by that it is considered as “AC” and audio transformers are routinely used.

Answer (score 3):

You have to read the code book to know 640.21 permanent audio systems states that they must comply with 725.

These circuits can be run above dropped ceiling but you can not use “speaker wire” these are usually classed as class 2 or 3 circuits and they can use the wall mount banana plugs with a “not a box” ring.

You are using CMP wire so wou would be good even if the dropped ceiling was a air handling area or plenum.